# How do rules cascade in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to learn to use Google Cloud Firestore for storing and securing some simple data, so I started writing some basic rules to verify that the data passed from the API is reasonable.

My initial thinking was that each rule would be evaluated and if any one failed it would fail the request, but I'm finding that requests and don't match a rule are still succeeding. Can someone explain how to create progressively stronger security rules for sub collections?

Here is my current ruleset:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    match /projects {
      allow write: if resource.data.keys().hasAll(['title', 'description']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "requests and don't match a rule are still succeeding" - it would be helpful if you could also post the queries/operations that you're successfully executing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Firestore Rules, if any `allow` grants the request, then the request is permitted. The `allow` statements applied to any given request are all `match` blocks that match the resource name.

Since the `match /{document=**}` pattern overlaps with the `match /projects` pattern, it will be possible to write to the `projects` document simply by being authenticated e.g. `request.auth.uid != null`. This was probably not what was intended.

The `match /projects` is fixed length match against `/databases/*/documents/projects`, whereas the `match /{document=**}` will match any document name that starts with `/databases/*/documents`. The presence of the `**` indicates zero or more additional paths.

In general, it is good practice to avoid overlaps in `match` patterns. If you need to write a rule which matches most things but carves out an exception for a specific path, it would need to be as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      // allow writes to anything except the 'projects' document.
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null
                   && /databases/$(database)/documents/$(document) 
                      != /databases/$(database)/documents/projects
    }
    match /projects {
      // allow _authenticated_ writes to the projects document if they
      // have the proper form.
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null
                   && resource.data.keys().hasAll(['title', 'description']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Funny coincidence with the names, thanks fellow Tristan! I ended up moving away from Firebase due to frustrations with the documentation but this is good advice and definitely would have solved my problem. I had assumed that rules would apply by specificity but once you know that it's first match it's not hard to write rules the way I had intended.

Answer (score 2):

I implement rules as follows:

1. Generic or Admin role rules match and execute first and thus fail first (if user is not an admin)
2. More Specific or Public role rules match and execute
3. Only if both 1 and 2 are false does the rule fail.

Once a rule returns true, you can't fail it or make it false again because of another match.

Note: Place your matches in order of most likely to return true most of the times in order to save on unnecessary charges.

Also try to create functions that you can reuse.

Here is one of the best resources I have found.
https://www.fullstackfirebase.com/cloud-firestore/security-rules